# Django query com timedelta dinâmico

Tags: django, filter

Olá, Estou enfrentando uma dificuldade inesperada para resolver esta query. 
Agradeço sua ajuda.

Tenho dois models:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    revision_period = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Period to revision'),
        help_text=_('Period, in years, for Revising Registrations'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Rating')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Ratings')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(
            self.titulo,
        )


class UserAssessment(models.Model):
    """
    Avaliação de riscos, conformidades, e fluxo de onboarding
    na visão do compliance.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    rating = models.ForeignKey(
        Rating,
        verbose_name=_('Rating'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    docs_revision_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_('Documents Revision Date'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

```
...
```

Preciso contar o numero de registros que estão vencidos ou irão vencer nos próximos 30 dias

"docs_revision_date" = informa a data da última revisão
"rating.revision_period" = informa o periodo - em anos - da revisão

Quero os registros que estouraram o prazo ( * 365 ) ou
Que vão estourar em 30 dias ( * 330 )

Minha última tentativa foi

```
    vencidos = len(UserAssessment.objects.filter(
        docs_revision_date__lte=make_aware(datetime.today())-timedelta(
            days='rating__revision_period' * 365), 
        docs_revision_date__lte=make_aware(datetime.today())-timedelta(
            days='rating__revision_period' * 330),

        )
    )
```

O problema é que eu não consigo colocar o período ('rating__revision_period') dentro
do timedelta()

alguém tem alguma orientação, pfv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, o que está tentando fazer não é possível a não ser que efetues a consulta previamente, porque estás a tentar filtrar com o seu próprio resultado ('rating__revision_period'), isso não é possível, pelo menos que eu conheça. Estive a analisar, não existe uma solução direta, a não ser iterar em todos 'Rating' e filtrar pelo seu id e utilizar o seu revision_period. Partilho um exemplo para analisares com a ideia. Neste caso estou a carregar um array com os querysets de resultado.

```
new_result = []
rating_objects = Rating.objects.all()
for item in rating_objects:
    new_result.append(
        UserAssessment.objects.filter(
                    rating_id = item.id,
                    docs_revision_date__lte=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)-timedelta(days=365 * item.revision_period),
                    docs_revision_date__lte=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)-timedelta(days=330 * item.revision_period))
        )
```

Comment: Atendeu perfeitamente. Parece óbvio agora! obrigado!